# is there a way to retrieve event, page or post from a specific country?

Tags: facebook, search, facebook-graph-api

I need to retrieve posts,events,pages from a  specific coutry.
I tried the search api with locale parameter but does not work.
With users, i found a way using fql but with those others entities  no way.
Any idea?
ciao

Answer (score 0):

Nope, it's not possible without constant querying the API for any public event (post/page), storing the event information in a local indexable data-store and then querying that data-store on the locale/location.  However, I'd recommend you should check with Facebook to see if it is permissible to do such an action of storing that data.

Answer (score 0):

The answer, unfortunately is No.

According to [this Facebook bug report](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/294623187324442/) it was a bug which prevented you at the time of asking this question. Later in 2013 they fixed the bug, but unfortunately it reappear in 2014, and it is still there.

To make Facebook more aware I opened a [new bug report](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1780033728983926/) today: